# Link to the new Street View feature of the google iOS web app

Tags: iphone, google-street-view

As Walt Mossberg von AllthingsD wrote, google added the Street View feature to the Web version of the Google Maps this Thursday.

I played around and it works very well inside Safari. My plan was to integrate this in my App with a direct link to Street View. In my case with some known lat and lng values. This is possible from a non iOS device as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/542965/956433

Sadly this does not work for iOS. Had anyone better luck and was able to build a link for some lat,lng values for Google Street View that works reliably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is obsolete now, with the release of the google maps app for iOS one is able to open the app and show streetview imagery directly. Everything is described here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

Thanks google :-)