# Obtain Google Street View via Latitude and Longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

It is possible access to Google Street View without passing via Google Map?

I have a graph with latitude and longitude. There is some tools for obtain the vision of Google Street View with only the knowledge of this two parameters?

Thank you in advance,
*Giacomo*

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview

Comment: OpenStreetMap provides raw map data, no street photos. But you can take a look at Mapillary instead.

Comment: Thank you @scai, but Mapillary do not cover the area of my interest. But is an interesting service.

Comment: Related (non-API version) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387942/google-street-view-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't  know if I understand your question correctly, but when you want to avoid the usage of the maps-API, you may embed an iframe, then you don't need to load/use the maps-API.

The URL would be:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&amp;cbll={latitude},{longitude}&amp;cbp=,{bearing},{tilt},{zoom},{pitch}&amp;source=embed&amp;output=svembed
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer isn't completely right, but helped me to find the result. Here are an example: https://www.google.it/maps/@43.726322,12.636374,0a,75y,90t/data=!3m3!1e1!3m1!2e0