# Google StreetView - Not very accurate when displayed using an URL with the "cbll" parameter

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

We try to show some adresses on StreetView using a link. We have the `latitude`/`longitude` for those adresses, and we open StreetView using :

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=[LATITUDE],[LONGITUDE]
```

This works, but StreetView is not positionned right in front of the adress. It is very near, but not perfect... Clearly not as accurate as when we search for the same adress *directly in Google Maps*, which adds a very precise marker right in front of the adress.

We even tried to use the Google [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) to convert the adresses to `latitude`/`longitude`... Same result : by using those lat/long in the URL for StreetView, the position is near but not that precise.

How we missing something?
Is the StreetView "*cbll*" parameter approximate by design?

Comment: It's stated in this [docu](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#display_a_street_view_panorama) that `cbll` accepts a latitude and a longitude as comma-separated values (46.414382,10.013988). The app will display the panorama photographed closest to this location. Because Street View imagery is periodically refreshed, and photographs may be taken from slightly different positions each time, **it's possible that your location may snap to a different panorama when imagery is updated**. For more info, check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387942).

Comment: @KENdi Thanks for you comment. I've already seen those other threads, sadly. Also, I don't think that this "nearest panorama" supposition is true... For many of those adresses, there *is* a more accurate panorama, right in front of the door, right in front of the marker itself Google puts on the map!