# Google Street View URL for Mobile - different results than Desktop

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view, google-maps-urls

The same URL gives different results via Mobile & Desktop.
A certain URL format for street view displays different results on different devices.

This is a starting reference for the URL's format: [Google street view URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387942/google-street-view-url)

When I load this URL: 
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=40.741895,-73.989308

in chrome via Desktop: I get a street view of a beach

in chrome via Android Mobile device: I get a street view of a street in New York (the correct response)

It seems that google presents via desktop a view (photo) that was made by a user and via Mobile a photo that was made by google.

But in another url: 
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=32.0522032,34.7633459

in chrome via Desktop: I get the correct street view, made by google

in chrome via Android Mobile device: "No results found for your search"

I guess this bug doesn't effect Google because they use a different entry point for street views in their services...

My goal is to present a Google Street View in a webview in an Android app and I'm trying to get the correct URL format for that.
Does anyone know what is the correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The officially supported and recommended by Google way is using [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#street-view-action). Google Maps URLs allow create universal cross-platform URLs that can be used both on desktop and mobile devices and support street view mode

> The pano action lets you launch a viewer to display Street View images as interactive panoramas. Each Street View panorama provides a full 360-degree view from a single location. Images contain 360 degrees of horizontal view (a full wrap-around) and 180 degrees of vertical view (from straight up to straight down). The pano action launches a viewer that renders the resulting panorama as a sphere with a camera at its center. You can manipulate the camera to control the zoom and the orientation of the camera.

You example may be rewritten using Google Maps URLs

https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&viewpoint=40.741895,-73.989308

However, unfortunately, it gives me a beach street view on desktop. I believe this is a data issue on Google side and you can report a problem to Google using the `Report a problem` link in bottom right corner of the map.

In the meantime I can suggest the following workaround. You can use [Street View API metadata](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata) service to get a pano ID of the point you are interested in

E.g. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?location=40.741895%2C-73.989308&source=outdoor&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Note that this service is free of charge and doesn't consume your quota

> Street View Static API metadata requests are free to use. No quota is consumed when you request metadata.

Also it supports a `source` parameter that allows filter out non-Google panoramas. In aforementioned example I get the following metadata response

```
{
  "copyright":"© Google, Inc.",
  "date":"2017-11",
  "location":{
    "lat":40.7419078,
    "lng":-73.9893223
  },
  "pano_id":"qH-ml27SSSYEXUCTT2NrhQ",
  "status":"OK"
}
```

So, now I can create a Google Maps URL using a pano ID that will open expected street view panorama

https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&pano=qH-ml27SSSYEXUCTT2NrhQ

I hope this helps!