# Need to Open the Address link in a Salesforce record as Google Street View rather than Map View

Tags: salesforce, google-street-view, google-street-view-static-api

I am a Salesforce administrator and I need to help my Sales team to save time.
During the day the Salespeople are required to view in Street View for each record but the address link takes them to Google Map view rather than the Street View.
How can I have it open in Street View?
I am trying to save a lot of clicks to a lot of people every day,
Please help me,

THank you

Comment: You seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/387942/313628 ? Do you have lat/long readily available or you need to "geocode" the address first?